# C# equivalent of php foreach loop on array

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I have the following for loop written in PHP:

```
$activesFilters = 0;

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {

    if(!empty($value)) $activesFilters++;

}

if(isset($_GET['Filter'])) { $activesFilters = $activesFilters - 1; }

if(isset($_GET['CustomFilter'])) { $activesFilters = $activesFilters - 1; }

if(isset($_GET['showArchived'])) { $activesFilters = $activesFilters - 1; }
```

and I want to convert it over to ASP.NET C# Razor.

So far I have:

```
int activeFilter = 0;

@foreach(Request.QueryString as key in value) {
   if(!empty(value)) activeFilters+1;
}

@if(Request.QueryString['Filter']) activeFilters = activeFilters - 1;

@if(Request.QueryString['CustomFilter']) activeFilters = activeFilters - 1;

@if(Request.QueryString['showArchived']) activeFilters = activeFilters - 1;
```

It's the `foreach` loop I'm confused about.

As I don't understand how to handle the `key => value` in C#

I've written the above based on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(v=vs.90).aspx but it doesn't show any examples for handling the key + value part.

**UPDATE:**

Based on some help from below:

```
@int activeFilters = 0;

@foreach (string key in Request.QueryString)
{
    string value = Request.QueryString[key];

    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)){
        return activeFilters+1;
    }

}
```

However it says `activeFilters` does not exist in the current context. How do I expose it to the `foreach` loop in C#? As this is fine in the PHP world.

Comment: So, what is the issue that you are having?

Comment: I have voted to close because this question demonstrates no effort in solving. A simple search would immediatly tell you how a `foreach` loop works in C#.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I did search to get to the code I have above in the question. Otherwise I wouldn't have anything to show. Not understanding how something works does not mean it demonstrates lack of effort! And assumptions that someone would 'immediately' understand something based on an article is condescending!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (string key in Request.QueryString)
{
    string value = Request.QueryString[key];
    // add your other code here
}
```

Now, you iterate over all keys in the query string, and then you get their values using `Request.QueryString[key]`.

Comment: Thanks for that. If you take a look at the code above. You can see what additional problem I have encountered with regards to the count of the values.

Comment: @Cameron: Just write `activeFilters++` or `activeFilters = activeFilters + 1`

Comment: Yeah tried that. But it says activeFilters doesn't exist. Even though I have declared it above the foreach loop?

Comment: @Cameron: Please see this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6601715/2619912

Comment: Oh WOW! C# is incredibly strict! :P Thanks